# How to represent a given equation more clear, profressional and short form?

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have a image $U_{m \times n}:\Omega \to \mathbb R^2$, the output $P$ can be define as
 $$P=\mu J_{m \times n} - U$$
where $\mu = \max \{ u_{ij} : 1 \leq i \leq m, 1 \leq j \leq n\}$, $J_{m \times n}$ be the $m \times n$ matrix whose $i, j$th component is $1$: that is, the all-ones matrix. (This notation isn't quite standard, but it's as close to standard as I know. $J$ is often the all-ones matrix)

However, it is so many sentences for expression the above equation. Do we have more short and standard way to represent it? As my found, the $J_{m \times n}$ can be expressed by indicator function such as

$$P=\max (U)\times 1_{\Omega}-U$$

where $1_{\Omega}$ is [Indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)

Does it equivalent with original meaning? If not, please give me a standard and common expression in image processing. Thanks

Comment: I would have defined $U_{m\times n}: [1,\ldots,m]\times [1,\ldots,n] \to \mathbb{R}$ instead, if you really want to have a professional notation. Unless your image is 2-valued, which would pose another challenge in defining a scalar $\max$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the notation $J_{m,n}$ is pretty standard for an [all-ones matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_of_ones). So the only possible clarification would be to dispense with $\mu$ and directly specify what it actually is:

$$P=||U||_{\max}J_{m,n}-U$$

where $||.||_{\max}$ denotes the [max norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Max_norm) of a matrix.

Comment: Thank Matt L. How about indicator function instead of $J$. Based on your comment, it will be $$P=||U||_{\max}1_{\Omega}-U$$

Comment: @user8430: I'm not sure if you could use it to specify the all-ones matrix. Furthermore, you would need to specify what the subset $\Omega$ is. I believe that using $J_{m,n}$ is much clearer, and probably the indicator function can't even actually be used in that way.

Comment: $\Omega$ is image domain, then $1_{\Omega}$ means 1 values in whole image domain. Actually, I want to reduce notation in that form. Thank for your max norm notation. For image processing, people do not like write form as size $J_{m \times n}$

Comment: The $J_{n\times n}$ is quite standard for the [counter-identity or exchange matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix) too, i.e. with ones on the second diagonal.

Comment: @LaurentDuval: Do you think my $1_{\Omega}$ can represent matrix of one?However, I found that $1_{\Omega}$ likes the function that map a domain in real value.

Comment: @Matt L. Plus, the sole $\max$ does not seem to be a mtrix norm to me, without the absolute value.

Comment: @LaurentDuval: What do you mean by 'sole max'? Check the link, $||.||_{\max}$ is a common notation for a matrix norm.

Comment: Of course, if you do check the link too, you can spot the use of absolute values, or magnitude

Comment: @LaurentDuval: I see what you mean, I knew about the magnitudes, but that's no problem for the application.

Comment: I believe there is no reason to impose a magnitude in the question. Seismic images are naturally zero-mean with negative and positive floating point values, and many operations (background removal) and mappings (wavelets) induce negative values, and one may want to perform the above operation on these results.

Comment: Image values are taken in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so so far, I consider they can be negative

Comment: @LaurentDuval: Fair enough, let's have the OP decide what his/her image values are.

Comment: @LaurentDuval: Due to image domain, I only consider gray image with its range from $0$ to $255$. Hence I think that Matt L. denotes $||.||_{\max}$ are enough. I only remain the matrix of one. I don't want to use notation $J$. I am looking for a better solution fo matrix of one denotation.

Comment: So I would suggest you to change the image value range in your question for clarity: $(\mathbb{R}^+)^2$. Or add absolute values to your $\max$. Unless it could be misleading for other users. For the one-matrix, you have an alternative proposal in my answer.

Comment: Yet I still believe that using a norm is a killer tool, as you do not use any norm property. You only revert values, setting the max to zero. One could also use $cos(\theta)+\imath sin(\theta)$ instead of $1$ because it looks a bit more complicated :)

Answer (score 1):

I would propose `\mathbb{1}` from the `\usepackage{bbold}` (or `\mathds{1}`, see [details and options here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26637/how-do-you-get-mathbb1-to-work-characteristic-function-of-a-set)), with outputs a $1$ with a double bar, like for $\mathbb{R}$ (I cannot have it displayed on SE). I would stick to a simple $\max $ or $\sup$, as it is not a norm without the absolute value. Plus, image values are taken in $\mathbb{R}^2$, as in  some [astronomical](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1999ASPC..172..125W), seismic or processed images. So, something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbold}
\begin{document}
$\max_{i,j} \{ A_{i,j}\} . \mathbb{1}-A$
\end{document}
```

[image: double-bar indicator notation]

Comment: I know of the [max norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Max_norm) of a matrix (as I've used it in my answer), but I'm not sure if $\max(A)$ is common notation. Wasn't that actually the point of your comment under my answer?

Comment: The max of all elements can be negative for instance. Hence it is not a norm. I beleive $\max_{i,j}$ is probably more readable. In my answer I wanted to emphasize on the double-bar one.

Comment: It is a norm, because it's the maximum of the absolute values of the matrix entries (check the link). This should be OK because we're talking about images (I know in the OP it was just the max, not max |.|, but it should make no difference for the application).

Comment: $\mathbb{1}$ doesn't work? It seems to for me: just use \mathbb{1} (in \$ signs).

Comment: It does not appear per se in my browsers (recent Firefox and Chromium). I do not understand why... yet